# Remove content of many subfolders that are names equally

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, find

My folder structure looks like this:

```
|-20200912
    -fringe
    -other
 
|-20200915
    -fringe
    -other 
...
```

And I want to delete the content of all folders called "fringe". How could I achieve this with one command?

I thought about something like this in pseudocode:

`find . -name "fringe" -type d -exec rm <content>`

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

```sh
find . -name 'fringe' -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

This removes every directory named `fringe` and everything within them.

Single vs double quotes don't make a difference here, but generally prefer single quotes if you mean to pass something in verbatim (with the possible exception of when the thing you want to pass in contains literal single quotes).

If you want to remove the directory's contents, try

```
... -execdir sh -c 'rm '*' \;
```

Comment: thanks a lot! But when I only want to remove the content and not the directory itself?  I saw something like a `find . -name 'fringe' -type d -exec rm -rf {}/*` but doesn't work quite yet

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to process the files and not the directory through rm and so I would use a regex that searches for for files with fringe in the directory path.

```
find -regex "^.*/fringe/.*$" -type f -exec rm '{}' \;
```

I would change the rm to ls to ensure that the results are expected before running the actual rm.

Answer (score 0):

You can force gobbing in the exec command:

```
find -name fringe -type d -execdir sh -c 'rm {}/*' \;
```